# LEGO or DUPLO ringing doorbell

Tags: part-identification, duplo

Does anyone know if this piece can be found anywhere or what it is called? 
My kids had a ringing doorbell appox 28 to 30 years ago, where you push down a red button that sits on top of a curved yellow DUPLO or LEGO piece. (similar in shape to an eyeball piece)

Answer (score 9):

I think you mean this part: [Duplo Brick 1 x 2 x 2 Rounded Top with Bell](http://www.peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/psearch?query=x836&limit=none)

[image]

It comes with 3 different prints.

There are several sellers on [bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?q=x836cx*) selling the part.